# Stop view height automatically changing on each screen size xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

In my view I set the height to: 200. But then when I switch to another screen size xcode changes its size. How can I make it the same height on all screens?

[image]

[image]

Then when I select another view the height has changed.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Constraints. They can use *either* the distance from - in this case - the top/bottom, *or* they can be set - again, in this case - to be an explicit height.

Comment: Where do you set the constraint for height to be a static number?

Comment: When I select the view and then go to set a height on the constraint it is greyed out.

Comment: While certain views (a UISlider for instance) have an intrinsic height you cannot change, this doesn't sound like the case for you. I don't use IB much, but I just create a new iOS project, opened up the main storyboard, add a simply UIView and clicked the next to last button (Add Constraints) and my height is enabled. There's a value because I dragged the view there, but I can (1) check the checkbox and (2) manually make a height. SO maybe my question is... *what* kind of view/control are you trying to set a height to?

Comment: Its a UIView I dragged onto the ViewController